# Move "Add to Wishlist" Button after "Add to Cart" in Product View

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, product-view-page

How to move "Add to wishlist" button after "Add to cart"?

I try using move but it's just working on the configurable products. I want it to work too on the simple products.

Check my **catalog_product_view.xml** :

```
...
  <move element="product.addto.wishlist" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" />
...
  <container name="product.addto.wishlist" as="product_addto_wishlist" htmlClass="product wishlist" htmlTag="div">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml"/>
  </container>
...
```

Add to Wishlist button is not showing on simple products.

[image: Simple Products]

**Configurable Products :**

## [image: Configurable Products]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got solutions for my problem.

Just create **catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml** and use this code below:

```
...
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml"/>
   </referenceBlock>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add below code to catalog_product_view.xml file for the simple and configurable product:

**For Simple Product**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
     <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" name="view.addto.wishlist" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml" />
 </referenceBlock>
```

**For Configurable Product**

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
     <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" name="view.addto.wishlist.bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml" />
 </referenceBlock>
```

It will look like:

**Wishlist in simple product**

### [image]

**Wishlist in Configurable Products**

[image]

---

Leave a comment if have any query

Comment: In my case I needed to change the template to `Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml`. Maybe it will be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
                        <move element="product.addto.wishlist" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" after="product.info.addtocart" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still not working. Add to Wishlist button not showing on simple products.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work @Emkalab

Answer (score 0):

Lo realice con esto

```
<move element="view.addto.wishlist" destination="product.info.form.options" after="-"/>
```